# put name and value of form into an array of objects [name: value]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, javascript-objects

I'm making a multi question survey and I'm trying to save name and value of my form into an object. I am able to put the name and value variables into an alert but I would like to see all the values in one hit, like an array with objects. JS code prints out [object Object] into the alert on the page:

```js
$("button[type='submit']").click(function() {
  //get name and value of each question and put into object
  $("input[type='radio']:checked").each(function() {
    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    var value = $(this).attr("value");
    var obj = {
      name: value
    };
    alert(obj);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="radio">
              <input type="radio" name="A1" value="1" required>
              <span class="radio__control-indicator"></span>1</label>
<label class="radio">
              <input type="radio" name="A1" value="2" required>
              <span class="radio__control-indicator"></span>2</label>

<label class="radio">
              <input type="radio" name="A2" value="1" required>
              <span class="radio__control-indicator"></span>1</label>
<label class="radio">
              <input type="radio" name="A2" value="2" required>
              <span class="radio__control-indicator"></span>2</label>
<button class="button button--primary right" type="submit">Submit Questionaire</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly note that this is exactly why you shouldn't use `alert()` for debugging; it coerces data types. Use `console.log(obj)` instead. Secondly you should use `val()` to get the value from form controls.

The major issue with your code is that you cannot use that syntax while providing a variable as the key of the object. You will need to use bracket notation instead, like this:

```js
$("button[type='submit']").click(function() {
  $("input[type='radio']:checked").each(function() {
    var obj = {};
    obj[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();
    console.log(obj);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="A1" value="1" required>
  <span class="radio__control-indicator"></span>1
</label>
<label class="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="A1" value="2" required>
  <span class="radio__control-indicator"></span>2
</label>

<label class="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="A2" value="1" required>
  <span class="radio__control-indicator"></span>1
</label>
<label class="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="A2" value="2" required>
  <span class="radio__control-indicator"></span>2
</label>
<button class="button button--primary right" type="submit">Submit Questionaire</button>
```

Also note that if you're intending to create an array of these objects, then `map()` would be a better solution:

```js
$("button[type='submit']").click(function() {
  var arr = $("input[type='radio']:checked").map(function() {
    var obj = {};
    obj[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();
    return obj;
  }).get();
  console.log(arr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="A1" value="1" required>
  <span class="radio__control-indicator"></span>1
</label>
<label class="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="A1" value="2" required>
  <span class="radio__control-indicator"></span>2
</label>

<label class="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="A2" value="1" required>
  <span class="radio__control-indicator"></span>1
</label>
<label class="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="A2" value="2" required>
  <span class="radio__control-indicator"></span>2
</label>
<button class="button button--primary right" type="submit">Submit Questionaire</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an `array` and `stringify` the array in order to show it.

A recommendation is logging that using `console.log()`.

```
var array = [];
$("input[type='radio']:checked").each(function(){  
    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    var value = $(this).attr("value");
    var obj = {name: value};
    array.push(obj);
});

console.log(array); // or console.log(JSON.strigify(array)) or alert(JSON.strigify(array)).
```

The output of console.log will be shown in the browser's developer tools.